# Making css work on all children

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML which I want which I want to format with some CSS

HTML:

```
<div class="photodetail table">
  <div class="photodetail row">
    <div class="photodetail cell">Date:</div>
    <div class="photodetail cell">Mar 24 2015 14:23:59</div>
  </div>
  <div class="photodetail row">
    <div class="photodetail cell">Camera:</div>
    <div class="photodetail cell">SAMSUNG GT-I9300</div>
  </div>
  <div> <-- THIS DIV
    <div class="photodetail row">
      <div class="photodetail cell">Country:</div>
      <div class="photodetail cell">Australia</div>
    </div>
    <div class="photodetail row">
      <div class="photodetail cell">City:</div>
      <div class="photodetail cell">Sydney</div>
    </div>
    <div class="photodetail row">
      <div class="photodetail cell">Adderss:</div>
      <div class="photodetail cell">123-125 York St, Sydney NSW 2000, Australia</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="photodetail row">
    <div class="photodetail cell">Id:</div>
    <div class="photodetail cell">31</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .table {
    display: table;
    .row {
      height: 26px;
      display: table-row;
      .cell {
        min-width: 53px;
        display: table-cell;
      }
    }
  }
```

This works fine for the first two rows, because the row sits directly under the table class. But the next 3 rows are embedded in a  which disturbes the picture.
How do I fix the css to take this into account?

I can not remove the extra  - it injected by react.

Comment: That's not CSS. That's less/sass or some sort of pre-processed code.

Comment: Yeah, you need to add tags for your CSS preprocessor or show us compiled CSS. Also, the solution might not be in your CSS but finding out why the extra element is there. Is it a row group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the above code, you could target it with the below and make the extra div display table

```
.table > div:not(.table) {
  display: table;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ktr6sa6y/1/

I added SCSS in the fiddle, if you are using LESS, it makes no difference in this case.

The best way to fix this would be when you inject it, just give it the table class or not inject the div at all. Maybe react need to inject it, I am not sure I have never used react